# debugging argpars in python

Tags: python, pycharm, argparse

May I know what is the best practice to debug an argpars function.

Say I have a py file test_file.py with the following lines

```
# Script start
import argparse
import os
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(“–output_dir”, type=str, default=”/data/xx”)
args = parser.parse_args()
os.makedirs(args.output_dir)
# Script stop
```

The above script can be executed from terminal by:

```
python test_file.py –output_dir data/xx
```

However, for debugging process, I would like to avoid using terminal. Thus the workaround would be

```
# other line were commented for debugging process
# Thus, active line are
# Script start
import os
args = {“output_dir”:”data/xx”}
os.makedirs(args.output_dir)
#Script stop
```

However, I am unable to execute the modified script. May I know what have I miss?

Comment: What did you write this in? You've got curly quotes and dashes in your code. If you're using a word processor instead of a text editor, that's a bad idea for programming.

Comment: `args` is a `Namespace` object, not a `dict`. However, for debugging you can simply pass an explicit list of arguments to `parse_args`, for example `args = parser.parse_args(["output_dir", "data/xx"])`.

Comment: HI @chepner thanks for the input. But may I know how to implement this for a multiple inputs with different class problem. I had posted the problem in a new [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50886471/debugging-argpars-in-python-multiple-inputs-with-diffrent-class). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used as a script, `parse_args` will produce a `Namespace` object, which displays as:

```
argparse.Namespace(output_dir='data/xx')
```

then

```
args.output_dir
```

will be the value of that attribute

In the test you could do one several things:

```
args = parser.parse_args([....])  # a 'fake' sys.argv[1:] list

args = argparse.Namespace(output_dir= 'mydata')
```

and use `args` as before.  Or simply call the

```
os.makedirs('data/xx')
```

I would recommend organizing the script as:

```
# Script start
import argparse
import os
# this parser definition could be in a function
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(“–output_dir”, type=str, default=”/data/xx”)

def main(args):
    os.makedirs(args.output_dir)

if __name__=='__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

That way the `parse_args` step isn't run when the file is imported.  Whether you pass the `args` `Namespace` to `main` or pass values like `args.output_dir`, or a dictionary, etc. is your choice.

Comment: HI @hpaulj, thanks for the input. While your suggestion work for single input, I am having difficulties in implementing it for  multiple input with different class problem. I post the problem in a new thread, which can be found in the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50886471/debugging-argpars-in-python-multiple-inputs-with-diffrent-class)

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in a shell script to do what you want

bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/

cd /path/to/my/script.py
python script.py --output_dir data/xx
```

If that is insufficient, you can store your args in a json config file

```
configs.json

{"output_dir": "data/xx"}
```

To grab them:

```
import json
with open('configs.json', 'rb') as fh:
    args = json.loads(fh.read())

output_dir = args.get('output_dir')

# 'data/xx'
```

Do take note of the double quotes around your keys and values in the json file

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. appreciate it.